# Android File Path NOT Found

Tags: android

I trying to do XML parsing program.
I also used **FileInputStream** for my XML file.
I placed XML file under android's assets folder,META-INF folder.
That's file name is "container.XML".

Here is my code parseXML,

```
 public void parseXMLinfoBook() throws FileNotFoundException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file:///android_asset/META-INF/container.xml");

        StringBuffer inLine = new StringBuffer();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

        BufferedReader inRd = new BufferedReader(isr);

        SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser spr=spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlreader = spr.getXMLReader();

        XmlHandler xmlhe=new XmlHandler();
        xmlreader.setContentHandler(xmlhe);

        }
```

Here is Button.SetonClick code,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    parseXMLinfoBook();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tv.setText("ErrorPath "+e.getMessage());
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

I got only error message.
Hope help!

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have placed your container.xml file in your application's assets directory inside the apk package.

To open files inside the /assets directory of your android app, you need an [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). The [getAssets()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) is available on the Context object and hence available to your Activity or Service.

```
AssetManager mgr = getContext().getAssets();
InputStream in = mgr.open("META-INF/container.xml");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
//... Rest of the code
```